# Removing constraints for data set

Tags: c#, dataset, constraints

I'm new to ASP.NET so this question may sound dumb but I really need help. I'm getting the error:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

So I decide to choose the quick way as suggested by Visual Studio: turn of constraints in my data set. From what I found on the Internet, the solution is to add `photoDataTable.EnforceConstraints = false;` but then I get another error:

> 'PhotoDataSet.PhotosDataTable' does not contain a definition for
>   'EnforceConstraints' and no extension method 'EnforceConstraints'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'PhotoDataSet.PhotosDataTable'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I'm wondering if I need to include any 'using' and if so, what should I include? Otherwise, what should I do? Please help.

Comment: A `DataTable` and a `DataSet` are different things. Set the [`EnforceConstraints` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.enforceconstraints.aspx) of the `DataSet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EnforceConstraints` is property of [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx), not [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I use only DataTable in my code so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Possibly you are violating local table constraints, not foreign keys.

Comment: It's strange because I don't have any constraints or foreign keys.

Comment: I do have primary key actually. Do you have any suggestion how to find out where the problem lies? I'm desperate now.

Comment: Possibly you have duplicate values in unique fields (for example, in primary key).